# Can I Play Cardinal Quest in a Window?

Tags: cardinal-quest

It looks like Cardinal quest always starts up in full-screen mode.  Is there any way I can switch the game mode to windowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> in the game, it should switch to windowed mode.

Comment: Would have been nice if that was displayed somewhere.